# How to check for Empty Bitmap while capturing Signature in Android

Tags: android, image, android-studio, bitmap, signature

I am using **com.github.gcacace.signaturepad.views.SignaturePad** for capturing signature in my android app. The getSignatureBitmap() returns a Bitmap object even for a blank screen. How do i check for a blank bitmap(blank screen) ?

Comment: use this for check empty bitmap : `bitmap != null`

Comment: The bitmap returns a bitmap object even when the empty screen is saved. So the bitmap is never null.

Answer (score 0):

Bitmap will always return an empty object. You can use the below trick to handle empty signature on signature-pad.

```
val isSinged = false
binding.signaturePad.setOnSignedListener(object: SignaturePad.OnSignedListener {
        override fun onStartSigning() {
            isSigned = true
        }

        override fun onSigned() {
            isSigned = true
        }

        override fun onClear() {
            isSigned = false
        }})
```

Use setOnSingedLister to check if user signed.